# `TypeError: store.dispatch(...).then is not a function` when trying to test async actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Trying to test my async action creators using this example: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html#async-action-creators and I think I did everything the same but I've got an error:

```
async actions › creates FETCH_BALANCE_SUCCEESS when fetching balance has been done

    TypeError: store.dispatch(...).then is not a function
```

Don't understand why it's happened because I did everything from the example step by step.

I also found this example http://arnaudbenard.com/redux-mock-store/ but anyway, mistake exists somewhere and unfortunately, I can't find it. Where is my mistake, why I've got an error even If my test case looks like the same as an example

My test case:

```
import nock from 'nock';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import * as actions from './';
import * as types from '../constants';

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);

describe('async actions', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    nock.cleanAll();
  });

  it('creates FETCH_BALANCE_SUCCEESS when fetching balance has been done', () => {
    const store = mockStore({});

    const balance = {};

    nock('http://localhost:8080')
      .get('/api/getbalance')
      .reply(200, { body: { balance } });

    const expectedActions = [
      { type: types.FETCH_BALANCE_REQUEST },
      { type: types.FETCH_BALANCE_SUCCEESS, body: { balance } },
    ];

    return store.dispatch(actions.fetchBalanceRequest()).then(() => {
      // return of async actions
      expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
    });
  });
});
```

My actions which I am trying to test.

```
import 'whatwg-fetch';
import * as actions from './actions';
import * as types from '../constants';

export const fetchBalanceRequest = () => ({
  type: types.FETCH_BALANCE_REQUEST,
});

export const fetchBalanceSucceess = balance => ({
  type: types.FETCH_BALANCE_SUCCEESS,
  balance,
});

export const fetchBalanceFail = error => ({
  type: types.FETCH_BALANCE_FAIL,
  error,
});


const API_ROOT = 'http://localhost:8080';

const callApi = url =>
  fetch(url).then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      return Promise.reject(response.statusText);
    }
    return response.json();
  });

export const fetchBalance = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(actions.fetchBalanceRequest());
    return callApi(`${API_ROOT}/api/getbalance`)
      .then(json => dispatch(actions.fetchBalanceSucceess(json)))
      .catch(error =>
        dispatch(actions.fetchBalanceFail(error.message || error))
      );
  };
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your test you have

```
return store.dispatch(actions.fetchBalanceRequest()).then(() => { ... })
```

You're trying to test `fetchBalanceRequest`, which returns an object, so you cannot call `.then()` on that. In your tests, you would actually want to test `fetchBalance`, since that is an async action creator (and that is what is explained in the redux docs you posted).

Answer (score 0):

That's usually a problem with redux-mock-store

Remember that:

import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store'

The function configureStore does not return a valid store, but a factory.

Meaning that you have to call the factory to get the store:

const store = configureStore([])()